# MonoTouch UIButton, UIPickerView and Overriding Readonly InputView

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Could someone please explain how I can create a `UIButton` which allows me to use the InputView / Accessory property (it is readonly by default) like in this article but using C# in MonoTouch

http://nomtek.com/tips-for-developers/working-with-pickers/

I have tried the basics, which will not compile -

```
public class CustomUIButton : UIButton
{
    public CustomUIButton()
    {

    }

    public CustomUIButton(RectangleF rect): base(rect)
    {

    }

    public override UIView InputView
    {
        get 
        {
            return base.InputView;
        }

        [ADDED] set { base.InputView = ""; }**
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample you linked to does **not** call the base class (in Objective-C) it fully implements the property.

C# does not like this, i.e. you can't override something that does not exists. However there's a few ways to work around this. The simplest one is to add a method for the setter. E.g.

```
class MyButton : UIButton {
    UIView input_view;

    public override UIView InputView {
        get {
            if (input_view == null)
                return base.InputView;
            return input_view;
        }
    }

    public void SetInputView (UIView view)
    {
        input_view = view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @poupou, thanks, I have used code above and overridden CanBecomeFirstResponder to true; but my UIPickerView is still not appearing on a button tap as it would with a UITextField, any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: Its ok, it now works great, the final piece of the jigsaw was to set button.BecomeFirstResponder in the buttons TouchUpInside handler.